# Subclassing, assignment operator and copy constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, copy, operator-keyword, subclassing

I have a bunch of questions related to this, I couldn't find exact answers.
Class A is the main class, and B is a subclass

1. If A::operator=(const A & other) was defined, does the default implementation of B::operator= copies members of B then calls A::operator= ?
2. If A copy constructor was defined, does the default implementation of the copy constructor for B copy-constructs members of B, then calls A copy constructor?
3. Do I need to define above functions virtual in A to get this behavior? (I suppose yes for operator= and no for the copy constructor, as virtual constructors is a nonsense?)
4. Can I forbid overloading the assignment operator or the copy constructor for subclasses of A, to force the use of default implementations?

The idea behind this, being to offer a plugin API for my users. I need the API to be C++ as scripts are too slow (I'll try JIT compilation one day), but it should be very simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If the default copy-assignment operator of class `B` is not deleted, [class.copy]/28

   > The implicitly-defined copy/move assignment operator for a non-union class `X` performs memberwise copy-/move assignment of its subobjects. The direct base classes of `X` are assigned first, in the order of their declaration in the *base-specifier-list* [i.e. in the order in which they're listed after `class X : /*here*/ {/*...*/};`], and then the immediate non-static data members of `X` are assigned, in the order in which they were declared in the class definition.
2. Similarly, [class.copy]/15

   > The implicitly-defined copy/move constructor for a non-union class X performs a memberwise copy/move of its bases and members.

   The order is: first the base class(es) (base class subobjects), then the direct non-static data members, similarly to 1).
3. For the behaviour described in 1) and 2), **no**. Virtual assignment operators are hardly ever useful. Constructors may not be virtual at all (doesn't make sense).

   In order for a virtual function in a derived class `B` to override a virtual function in a base class `A`, it must have the same parameter types. That is, you could have a `virtual A& operator=(A const&);` in the base class `A`, but the override in class `B` had to look like `virtual B& operator=(A const&);`, which is **not** a copy-assignment operator for `B`, because of the parameter type.
4. Not without "hacks". And you're not actually overloading it, but hiding all base class assignment operators. Otherwise, this would be legal:

   ```
   class A {};
   class B { int i; };

   A a;
   B b = a; // using A::operator=(A const&)
   ```